# Updating the selected object in a SwiftUI List

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

When using a List is SwiftUI, I have code to update the selected object which works fine. However the change to the selected object is not reflected in the List until the selected object changes.

Here is a simplified version of the class my List is displaying.

```swift
class Item: ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

extension Item: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}
```

And here is a simplified version of my view.

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State var items = [
        Item(name: "Item 1"),
        Item(name: "Item 2"),
        Item(name: "Item 3"),
        Item(name: "Item 4")
    ]
    @State var selectedItem: Item?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(items, id: \.self, selection: $selectedItem) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Button { items.append(Item(name: "New Item")) }
                    label: { Text("Add Item") }
                
                Button { selectedItem?.name += "a" }
                    label: { Text("Update Item") }
                    .disabled(selectedItem == nil)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I was going to use the range `0..<items.count` and update the object within the array, however this crashes when the number of items changes.

Screen recording:
[image: Screen recording]

Comment: Rather than `@State` for your array of Items, you would want to use `@ObservedObject`, since `Item` is an `ObservableObject` with `name` as its `@Published` property.

Comment: @MStrapko Unfortunately that doesn't work for as an array itself doesn't conform to ObservableObject (and is in fact itself a struct and not a class).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your items have reference type (`class Item`) the references in State array are not changed when you modify each of objects, so view is not refreshed.

The possible solution to your model is to separate list row into standalone view that will observe corresponding item changes

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / macOS 10.15.6

```
struct ListRowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item

    var body: some View {
        Text(item.name)
    }
}
```

so main list becomes

```
List(items, id: \.self, selection: $selectedItem) { item in
    ListRowView(item: item)
}
```

Comment: Ahhh genius! I'd never even considered I could use `@ObservedObject` for an object that was inside an array.